# Why I get this JSON Deserialize Object error message

Tags: json, vb.net, json-deserialization

I call an API which return a JSON.  This is the API call:

https://wax.api.atomicassets.io/atomicmarket/v1/sales?state=1&collection_name=hotwheels&template_id=353670&page=1&limit=1&order=asc&sort=price&timestamp=1654317900790

I ran the JSON result on this website to generate the class :
https://json2csharp.com/

After I converted the result to VB.net from the Telerik conversion tool:
https://converter.telerik.com/

It gave me the following class which I included in a class called : HWMarketplace

```
Public Class Asset
    Public Property contract As String
    Public Property asset_id As String
    Public Property owner As String
    Public Property is_transferable As Boolean
    Public Property is_burnable As Boolean
    Public Property collection As Collection
    Public Property schema As Schema
    Public Property template As Template
    Public Property mutable_data As MutableData
    Public Property immutable_data As ImmutableData
    Public Property template_mint As String
    Public Property backed_tokens As List(Of Object)
    Public Property burned_by_account As Object
    Public Property burned_at_block As Object
    Public Property burned_at_time As Object
    Public Property updated_at_block As String
    Public Property updated_at_time As String
    Public Property transferred_at_block As String
    Public Property transferred_at_time As String
    Public Property minted_at_block As String
    Public Property minted_at_time As String
    Public Property sales As List(Of Object)
    Public Property auctions As List(Of Object)
    Public Property prices As List(Of Price)
    Public Property data As Data
    Public Property name As String
End Class

Public Class Collection
    Public Property collection_name As String
    Public Property name As String
    Public Property img As String
    Public Property author As String
    Public Property allow_notify As Boolean
    Public Property authorized_accounts As List(Of String)
    Public Property notify_accounts As List(Of Object)
    Public Property market_fee As Double
    Public Property created_at_block As String
    Public Property created_at_time As String
End Class

Public Class Data
    Public Property eula As String
    Public Property make As String
    Public Property name As String
    Public Property legal As String
    Public Property model As String
    Public Property video As String
    Public Property cardid As String
    Public Property rarity As String
    Public Property backimg As String
    Public Property designer As String
    Public Property collection As String
    Public Property redeemable As Integer
    Public Property description As String
    <Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("redeem date")>
    Public Property RedeemDate As String
    <Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("release date")>
    Public Property ReleaseDate As String
    <Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("year released")>
    Public Property YearReleased As String
    Public Property market_contract As String
    Public Property assets_contract As String
    Public Property sale_id As String
    Public Property seller As String
    Public Property buyer As Object
    Public Property offer_id As String
    Public Property price As Price
    Public Property listing_price As String
    Public Property listing_symbol As String
    Public Property assets As List(Of Asset)
    Public Property maker_marketplace As String
    Public Property taker_marketplace As Object
    Public Property collection_name As String
    Public Property is_seller_contract As Boolean
    Public Property updated_at_block As String
    Public Property updated_at_time As String
    Public Property created_at_block As String
    Public Property created_at_time As String
    Public Property ordinality As String
    Public Property state As Integer
End Class

Public Class Format
    Public Property name As String
    Public Property type As String
End Class

Public Class ImmutableData
    Public Property eula As String
    Public Property make As String
    Public Property name As String
    Public Property legal As String
    Public Property model As String
    Public Property video As String
    Public Property cardid As String
    Public Property rarity As String
    Public Property backimg As String
    Public Property designer As String
    Public Property collection As String
    Public Property redeemable As Integer
    Public Property description As String
    <Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("redeem date")>
    Public Property RedeemDate As String
    <Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("release date")>
    Public Property ReleaseDate As String
    <Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("year released")>
    Public Property YearReleased As String
End Class

Public Class MutableData
End Class

Public Class Price
    Public Property token_contract As String
    Public Property token_symbol As String
    Public Property token_precision As Integer
    Public Property median As Object
    Public Property amount As String
End Class

Public Class Price2
    Public Property market_contract As String
    Public Property token As Token
    Public Property median As String
    Public Property average As String
    Public Property suggested_median As String
    Public Property suggested_average As String
    Public Property min As String
    Public Property max As String
    Public Property sales As String
End Class

Public Class Root
    Public Property success As Boolean
    Public Property data As List(Of Data)
    Public Property query_time As Long
End Class

Public Class Schema
    Public Property schema_name As String
    Public Property format As List(Of Format)
    Public Property created_at_block As String
    Public Property created_at_time As String
End Class

Public Class Template
    Public Property template_id As String
    Public Property max_supply As String
    Public Property is_transferable As Boolean
    Public Property is_burnable As Boolean
    Public Property issued_supply As String
    Public Property immutable_data As ImmutableData
    Public Property created_at_time As String
    Public Property created_at_block As String
End Class

Public Class Token
    Public Property token_symbol As String
    Public Property token_precision As Integer
    Public Property token_contract As String
End Class
```

Then from my VB.net code, I run these lines :
The variable strURL is declare previously in my code and it's the URL mentioned at the beginning of my message

```
            Dim strJson As String = String.Empty
            Dim myHttpWebRequest As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(strURL), HttpWebRequest)
            myHttpWebRequest.Timeout = 500000
            With myHttpWebRequest
                .Method = "GET"
                .ContentType = "application/json"
                .Accept = "application/json"
            End With

            Dim myHttpWebResponse As HttpWebResponse = CType(myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
            strJson = New StreamReader(myHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd()

            myHttpWebResponse.Dispose()
            Dim myNFT As HWMarketplace.Root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of HWMarketplace.Root)(strJson)
```

And I get this error:
Exception thrown: 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' in Newtonsoft.Json.dll

ex.Message :
"Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path 'data[0].collection', line 1, position 5018."

I would need a bit of help figuring why it doesn't work?  I generated the class from the result, it should be ready to deserialize it with success.

I did the same process for other methods in that same API and it worked perfectly but this one seems to cause problems.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: I can not see any deserialization code at all

Comment: Oh!  I was missing the deserialization line of code.  I added it at the end.

Comment: Your `Data` class has been mixed with the `ImmutableData` class. The `collection` member should be a class object, not a string. -- Instead of converting from C#, post your JSON here: [JSON Utils](https://jsonutils.com/), which will generate VB.Net classes directly. Tick `PascalCase` and select `JsonProperty` from the combo.

Comment: To add to what @Jimi stated. When using [JSON Utils](https://jsonutils.com/), it seems to generate two `Price` classes. Change the name of the `Price` class that has 9 properties to `Price2`. Then in class `Asset` change from `Public Property Prices As Price()` to `Public Property Prices As Price2()`.

Comment: Thank you @Jimi and user9938.  I made the changes and it worked.  I will revise the differences between the class I was using versus the one generated from the suggested site to have a better understanding.  I am new to all this so this case will definitely help me improve in future developments.  Your replies were very helpful.